# Why is phone storage breakdown not adding up

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, motorola-moto-g2

When I go into the internal storage menu,  the subsections (only apps and cache because I use adoptable storage) do not add up to the total internal storage space used. What is not being shown?

[image: internal stage view] [image: os displayed here.]

Edit: so I have kept looking around, and I hoped to get to the bottom of this with a storage visualization app, but they always seem to show the wrong partitions. Does anyone have any input?

Answer (score 1):

The Android operating system itself and other programs that come pre-installed on your phone are also saved to internal storage. This is why the available storage will never equal the advertised storage capacity on any new phone.

Some bloatware can be uninstalled and some cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  but I thought that was displayed up one menu. I am adding that photo to my main submission.